# Including a non-relevant work experience in Statement of Purpose for higher studies abroad

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose, changing-fields, time-off

After completing my undergraduate studies in Biotechnology, I switched to a career in Banking services where I have worked for a year. But now I would like to pursue higher studies abroad in biological sciences and I don't know how exactly I am supposed to include my work experience in my SOP. Since, my work experience is not related to my program of interest, how should I approach this issue?

Comment: I'd suggest including in your SOP just as much about banking as you've included in your question here. That is, give it about half a sentence and then move on to relevant things.

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/58440/should-you-list-irrelevant-work-experience-on-graduate-school-applications

Comment: Just a blank stretch in your time line *does* look bad.

Comment: Juat describe things as they are - there is no way around it.